# How to repeat an input for an input

Tags: python

I have been trying to get my code to repeat for a list it works if it is left blank but if the input is above 4 in breaks, I'm still trying to get the hang of python

I've tried finding a solutions for this but can't figure out what needs to be where it should go

```
#Create a list for when they select the computer they want
ComputerList = ["(1)Home Basic $900", "(2)Office $1200", "(3)Gamer $1500", "(4)Studio $2200"]
#Ask them what they want and repeat if left blank
while True:
    ComputerChoice = input("What computer would you like to buy?(Use the number beside it 1-4): ")
    print("")
    try:
        ComputerChoice_int = int(ComputerChoice)
    except ValueError:
        print("You can not leave this blank '%s', try again" % (ComputerChoice,))
        print("")
    else:
        break
```

I expected it to repeat but it comes up with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\hnhs-fs01\StudentUsers$\17031\Documents\11 DTG\1.7\Assement\Assessment computer.py", line 69, in <module>
    Computer = ComputerList[ComputerChoice_int -1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: The error trace you showed points to a line that is not shown in the code you have provided.  However, the error is generated when you enter in an option that is not between 1 and 4.  You should add this check in once you read in the number from the user.

Comment: In Python we usually [name variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) using `lowercase_with_underscores`, the style of `CapitalLetters` is used for class definitions.

Comment: You don't need to pass the empty string to print, `print()` on its own will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem ? This code works perfectly.

```
#Create a list for when they select the computer they want
ComputerList = ["(1)Home Basic $900", "(2)Office $1200", "(3)Gamer $1500", "(4)Studio $2200", "test (5)"]
#Ask them what they want and repeat if left blank
while True:
    print(ComputerList)
    ComputerChoice = input("What computer would you like to buy?(Use the number beside it 1-%s): " % len(ComputerList))
    try:
        ComputerChoice_int = int(ComputerChoice) - 1
        if not -1 < ComputerChoice_int < len(ComputerList):
            raise ValueError
        print("ok")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Something went bad :/\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, using `int(input())` makes everything a lot nicer + you don't have to except errors.

```
ComputerList = ["(1)Home Basic $900", "(2)Office $1200", "(3)Gamer $1500", "(4)Studio $2200"]

while True:
    ComputerChoice = int(input("What computer would you like to buy?(Use the number beside it 1-4): "))

    if ComputerChoice not in range(1,5):
        print("invalid input")
    else:
        print("You selected {}".format(ComputerList[ComputerChoice-1]))
        # Do whatever here
```

Answer (score 0):

Its crashing because you have no clause to catch input greater than 4. Its only raising an error if the field is not convertible to an integer. Now you could hardcode the 4 in, but a more reliable method is to use the length of the list. This makes your code more easy to update if you add or remove computers.

Heres what I would do:

```py
ComputerList = ["(1)Home Basic $900", "(2)Office $1200", "(3)Gamer $1500", "(4)Studio $2200"]

max_integer = len(ComputerList)
status = False 
while status == False:
   try:
      Choice = int(input("enter your choice"))
      if 0 < Choice <= max_integer:
         status = True
   except ValueError:
      print('input is invalid')
      pass
```

This can be shortened up but I drew it out a bit so you understand whats happening

Comment: What if `Choice` is 0 or negative?  Also, adding in a sentinel flag is unnecessary.  You can just use `break` when needed and let the loop go on forever until a valid input is used (i.e. `while True`).

Comment: Edited in how you would deal with it being 0 or negative. And like always there are many ways to do something, and like stated im trying to keep it very obvious whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you are catching just ValueError like strings or empty values. The number 4 is not an error because 4 is an integer. If you want to handle with ValueError and IndexError you need to do it:

```
#Create a list for when they select the computer they want
ComputerList = ["(1)Home Basic $900", "(2)Office $1200", "(3)Gamer $1500", "(4)Studio $2200"]
#Ask them what they want and repeat if left blank
while True:
    ComputerChoice = input("What computer would you like to buy?(Use the number beside it 1-4): ")
    print("")
    try:
        ComputerChoice_int = int(ComputerChoice)
        Computer = ComputerList[ComputerChoice_int -1]
    except Exception as e:
        if e.__class__.__name__ == "ValueError":
            print("You can not leave this blank '%s', try again" % (ComputerChoice,))
            print("")
        elif e.__class__.__name__ == "IndexError":
            print("You can not input numbers bigger than {}, try again".format(len(ComputerList)))
            print("")
    else:
        break
```